# Return ForeignKeys in SubSonic.Query

Tags: subsonic

I have a table that possesses ForeignKeys 
In this code below that am using only the columns of the table informed in the parameter is return

```
public DataSet Store_RefreshData(string Table){
        Query q = new Query(Table);
        return q.ExecuteDataSet();
}
```

Precise to come back a field "descricao" of the related table using a SubSonic.Query.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a stored procedure, then call it like so:

```
var db = new NorthwindDB();
StoredProcedure sproc = db.ListProductsWithSuchAndSuch();
DataSet results = sproc.ExecuteDataSet();
```